# Include context (before/after) on filtered network packages

Tags: networking, tcp, wireshark

Having Problems with my implementation of a network-protocol (LTi ServoOne), I analyzed network traffic with wireshark.

The error occurs ~once in 12h, so I have lots of packages. I'm able to filter the packages which trigger the error:
`tcp.analysis.duplicate_ack || tcp.analysis.retransmission`

With that filter I only get specific packages - what i need, is also the packets that were sent immediately before and after (~5 packets)

QUESTION: How can I include `n` packets before and `m` packets after each packet, that matches a capture / display filter in wireshark?